# Implementing Parse Push Notification

Tags: android, eclipse, parse-platform

I want to use Parse SDK with my android project in Eclipse, but I don't know how to do this because all the tutorials are for Android Studio and Gradle. How can I use this in Eclipse?

Comment: Did you check Parse Android Docs at Parse.com?

Comment: yes, but all are from android studio and gradle

Comment: No, they're not. They are very easy to understand and detailed and would work on any platform.

Comment: then, I don't know where it is. there is only this https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/existing and is from android studio and gradle

Comment: Same problem here... I'll try to somehow hack it out, but will be nice if you have and can share your solution

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard:

1. [Download Parse SDK](https://parse.com/downloads/android/Parse/latest)
2. Unzip it
3. Drop Parse-*.jar and bolts-android-*.jar into `libs` in your Eclipse project
4. Add all the neccesary lines of code as described in [Quick Start Guide](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/existing). Obviously you'll need to add some imports:

   import com.parse.Parse;
   import com.parse.ParseInstallation;

Hmmm, I think that was it - let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score -1):

Simply go to Parse.com and open your application's setting page. Then open 'Push' tab and toggle the 'Client push enabled?', [More Info Here.](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending/Android)

See the image for clarity:

[image]

Comment: well, but what I have tried is install parse in eclipse first

Comment: [you need to go through this](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide). It got step by step details about how to implement Parse

Comment: Download Parse SDK for android and then copy Parse*.jar to your project. Then open your project properties and then `Java Build Path`. Then click on Add Jar. Then add Parse*.jar to your project.

Comment: Then clarify your statement. What exactly do you want?

Comment: I want to import parse sdk in eclipse and kwno how to use the permissions and code from use parse in to my project

Comment: You can [download this](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/f8DeveloperConferenceApp) tutorial and import it to your eclipse.

Comment: I have just get implent this, but when I launch the app, throws this error: java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: com.parse.parse and I added the .jar to my project

Comment: What about the Keys? Open ParseApplication.java file and fill your keys, only then it will work. Did you put them?

Comment: If I toggle to Off and still have code in my app, will it crash?

Comment: @MikeClark, If the code is right then no, it will send "false" in the callback and you can perform actions accordingly.

Comment: I think you dont understand the problem @UncaughtException - he simply needs steps on how to integrate Parse SDK into Eclipse project (not Android Studio as Parse offers it)